# Align single item to center in RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gravity

> Suppose I have one OR two items in `RecyclerView` . How could I display them in **center** 
>    **RecyclerView must have width and height is match_parent**

**AFAIK** `recyclerView` starts from `top`. How could I give `gravity = center` to its `single item`. I mean if only 1 item comes it should be in the center of screen.
**RecylerView** doesn't have `gravity attribute`. Is there any other way round.

I can't set it's height to wrap_content. Because I also have to add a swipeRefreshLayout.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/MatchMatch"
    android:background="@color/theme_color_gift_finder">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_gift_menu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_pad_10" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
            style="@style/LinearHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_pad_16"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.netsolace.efc.utility.customviews.widgets.CustomButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_go"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_go_n_done_btn_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_go_n_done_btn_size"
                android:background="@drawable/oval_generic"
                android:text="@string/go"
                android:textColor="@color/theme_color_gift_finder"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.netsolace.efc.utility.customviews.widgets.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_gift_no_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No Results"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you consider of showing single list item in the centre then I would suggest to get another layout which has a `layout_height` and `layout_width` set to `match_parent` and then set the list item when your list contains only one item.

So inside your `onCreateViewHolder` of your adapter, do something like this

```
// Declare a constant named SINGLE_VIEW first, inside your Adapter
private final int SINGLE_VIEW = 1;

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v;

    if (viewType == SINGLE_VIEW) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_single, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    } else {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;

    }
}
```

Then in `getItemViewType` you need to `return` proper view.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 0 && yourList.size() == 1) return SINGLE_VIEW;
    else return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

**Update**

If you need to put your `RecyclerView` in the centre of the screen then you need to design your layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The important things to pick up from above code is setting the `gravity` of the parent `RelativeLayout` to centre and set the height of the `RecyclerView` to `wrap_content`.

Here's my test application screenshot

[image: Here's my test application screenshot]

Comment: I want to center the item shown in recyclerView .It may be 1,2 or 5. Depend on visible item shown in a device. I want to center them.

Comment: Reaz Murshed I mention that I have a SwipeRefresh above RecyclerView. It wouldn't work if I use height =wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the adapter with multiple viewTypes and have a special type for a solo item, where its layout_height="match_parent". Or you can customize the single item in that case by adjusting its layout params, however you will need to ensure you reset them for other items (that get recycled).

Answer (score -2):

Use following:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```